# Is it possible to make sure only one row in an Android Room database contains a boolean value 'true'?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I want to have a list of accounts saved by the user, but there should be one active account, therefore there should be one account flagged with isActive=true in the Android Rooms Database.

Is this possible? The only thing I could find was that Android Room saves a boolean as 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another possibility would be to save the ID or name of the active account to the shared preferences. This way you would have only one value to check to find out which account is active. And you would save many queries of checking which account is active in your DB or updating all entries when changing the active account.

Regarding your question. I think it should be important to consider how you intend to use this `boolean` value and when and in which context it should be queried. You really should ask yourself if it is beneficial to your application that your entity class has this field and does "know" about its state being active or not. On Query, Room maps the SQLite data to your specified Entity class. In fact, you are just using this runtime object for doing something with the data. Personally, I feel that logic-wise it makes more sense that not the entity itself knows that it is active. But something that is handling/managing your account entities.
From this point of view, what you are asking is: whenever an account is declared active, let all other accounts (data) know that they are not active.
You mentioned these accounts belong to a user. Then does this user have its own entity? If yes, then could you store the account reference there?

Comment: This is not a bad idea, and probably my way forwards at this moment. If there's no direct solution to my question I will mark this as the answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you have users table it is better to have column [active_account] in that table and store there an id of currently active account. If you have just accounts table you can use shared preferences to store active account id (as mentioned in cewaphi's answer). I think having flag isActive just on one record is really bad design.

Answer (score 2):

Before setting a row to `true`, query the database for all rows that have a `true` value and set them to `false`.

Comment: I have thought of this, but it looks to me like it would cause a lot of (imho unnecessary) db operations. I was hoping there would be an easier way.

Comment: Database operations are super efficient. And, besides, it's only a couple light operations and they're only running every time someone logs in (not very often).